# What is the default hash of user defined classes?

Tags: python, hash, cpython

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-hashable) incorrectly claim that

> Objects which are instances of user-defined classes are hashable by default; they all compare unequal (except with themselves), and their hash value is their `id()`

Although I recall this being correct once, such objects hashing equal to their id is apparently not true in current versions of python (v2.7.10, v3.5.0).

```
>>> class A:
...     pass
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> hash(a)
-9223372036578022804
>>> id(a)
4428048072
```

In [another part](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) of the docs it's said that the hash is *derived* from the id.  When/why did the implementation change, and **how is the number returned by hash "derived from" the id now?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The relevant function appears to be:

```
Py_hash_t
_Py_HashPointer(void *p)
{
    Py_hash_t x;
    size_t y = (size_t)p;
    /* bottom 3 or 4 bits are likely to be 0; rotate y by 4 to avoid
       excessive hash collisions for dicts and sets */
    y = (y >> 4) | (y << (8 * SIZEOF_VOID_P - 4));
    x = (Py_hash_t)y;
    if (x == -1)
        x = -2;
    return x;
}
```

(that code comes from [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1fe0fd9feb6a4472a9a1b186502eb9c0b2366326/Python/pyhash.c#L131), and is then used to be the `tp_hash` slot in `type` [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/typeobject.c#L4428).) The comment there seems to give a reason for not using the pointer (which is the same thing as the `id`) directly. Indeed, the commit that introduced that change to the function is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/98f1f9e473acf3d0142385fc59a45430b5e043d7), and states that the reason for the change is:

> Issue #5186: Reduce hash collisions for objects with no **hash**
>   method by   rotating the object pointer by 4 bits to the right.

which refers to [this](http://bugs.python.org/issue5186) issue, which explains more why the change was made.

Answer (score 2):

This changed in 2009, as a result of [issue #5186](http://bugs.python.org/issue5186); the usual `id()` values caused too many collisions:

```
In the issue 5169 discussion, Antoine Pitrou suggested that for an object 
x without a `__hash__` method, `id()/8` might be a better hash value than 
`id()`, since dicts use the low order bits of the hash as initial key, and 
the 3 lowest bits of an `id()` will always be zero.
```

The [current implementation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/object.c#l1080) takes the id and rotates it to produce a more varying value:

```c
long
_Py_HashPointer(void *p)
{
    long x;
    size_t y = (size_t)p;
    /* bottom 3 or 4 bits are likely to be 0; rotate y by 4 to avoid
       excessive hash collisions for dicts and sets */
    y = (y >> 4) | (y << (8 * SIZEOF_VOID_P - 4));
    x = (long)y;
    if (x == -1)
        x = -2;
    return x;
}
```

This resulted in a 14% to 34% speedup, depending on the test performed.

The glossary is simply out of date; I see you [already opened an issue with the project](http://bugs.python.org/issue25574).